# Replacing the chip problem

Tags: logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

There are $13$ white, $15$ black, $17$ red chips on a table. In one step, a person
may choose $2$ chips of different colors and replace each one by a chip of
the third color. Can all chips become the same color after some steps?

Comment: You should really **mention the source where you got this question from**. It's a fairly commonly seen exercise, but your wording is almost identical to that of Arthur Engel, *Problem-Solving Strategies*, chapter 1, problem 6 (reproduced e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330516/problem-from-olympiad-book-by-arthur-engel-invariant-problem) and [here](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~hayward/272/variants.pdf), page 20)..

Comment: no, it is different to both if those problems,  the first replaces 2 with 2, the second asks for a single piece remaining.  a solution is to make a white chip and then make red chips until all the black and white are used up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is impossible. Note that the pairwise differences between the three colors are 2, 2, and 4. Furthermore, the operation described—turning $(a, b, c)$ into $(a+2, b-1, c-1)$—changes the differences between any two colors by either 3 or 0.  In order to obtain all chips of a single color, we need counts $(45, 0, 0)$, which has a pair with difference 0. However, it is not possible to get from either 2 or 4 to 0 in steps of 3, so this cannot be done.